# How does a string returned from a SQL select statement get encoded?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Here's a sample string, stored in a MySQL database, running on a Linux server: ™

That's the single TM character, which is represented as `0x2122` in `UTF-16BE`, or `0xE284A2` in `UTF-8`

The database table is encoded in `utf8-unicode-ci`.  I'm running PHP on another Linux server, which uses an internal encoded (as reported by `mb_internal_encoding`) of `ISO-8859-1`, which uses the same encoding for the character as UTF-8.

When I run a SQL query to get the string, it returns `0x0099`, which is its representation in `Windows-1252`.

How would that even happen, and how can I fix it to return in a more sensible codepage?

Comment: `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');` is preferred to executing a SET NAMES statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you observe is due to the default MySQL client characterset.

You can override the default, and specify the characterset that is to be used for the client connection.  If you are using mysqli, then do this:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

see:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html